# How to invoke SignalR Clients.All.InvokeAsync() in places other than the Controller?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm able to access my `IHubContext<MyHub>` fine and dandy in my .NET Core WebAPI's Controller through DI in the constructor, but I want to access it elsewhere too.

Specifically, when I consume a message from RabbitMQ, sometimes I want to update clients through `_myHubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync()`, but I just can't figure out how to get it.

I'm also having issues finding documentation for doing this kind of thing outside of the controller.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

To add some detail, and where the cause of my problem may originate, I'm trying to access the IHubContext (and some of my own services registered in `ConfigureServices`) within my `Startup` class, specifically during `IApplicationLifetime` `ApplicationStarted` and `ApplicationStopped` which call a RabbitMQ consumer's methods to connect and disconnect.

I'm I correct in guessing that maybe I'm unable to access registered services in the `Startup` class? If so, how would I go about starting these services?

**Update:**

Moving `services.AddSignalR()` and some of the services that are called at startup one level up to the `WebHost.ConfigureServices` in `Program.cs` solved some of my problems, but of course there are more.

I wasn't getting any messages on my JS client when I received a message from RabbitMQ, but my client was connecting successfully. "Weird..." I thought. To get more info, I wired up a an GET action in my controller to sent some content through the SignalR `Hub`. Whenever I called that GET, it works... the `IHubContext<MyHub>`. I get the `hubContext` through the constructor in my RabbitMQ listener, just like I do with the controller.

The new question: are things injected differently in the controller than they are into services that I register myself at startup? How so, and how do I overcome that?

Some code to go with it...

**Excerpt from `Program.cs`**

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddTransient<ISubscriber, Subscriber>();
            services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();
            services.AddTransient<IHealthCheckProcessor, HealthCheckProcessor>();
            services.AddTransient<INodeProcessor, NodeProcessor>();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

**From `Startup.cs`**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration _configuration, ISubscriber _subscriber)
    {
        configuration = _configuration;
        subscriber = _subscriber;
    }
    public IConfiguration configuration { get; }
    public ISubscriber subscriber { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            // CORS stuff);

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<StatusHub>("Status");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStartup);
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
    }

    private void OnStartup() {
        // MessageBroker stuff
        subscriber.Start(messageBroker);
    }

    private void OnShutdown() {
        subscriber.Stop();
    }
}
```

**From `Subscriber.cs`**

```
public class Subscriber : ISubscriber {
    public static IConnection connection;
    public static IModel channel;
    public IHubContext<StatusHub> hubContext;

    public static IHealthCheckProcessor healthCheckProcessor;
    public static INodeProcessor nodeProcessor;

    public Subscriber(IHubContext<StatusHub> _hubContext, INodeProcessor _nodeProcessor, IHealthCheckProcessor _healthCheckProcessor)
    {
        connection = new ConnectionFactory().CreateConnection();
        channel = connection.CreateModel();
        hubContext = _hubContext;
        nodeProcessor = _nodeProcessor;
        healthCheckProcessor = _healthCheckProcessor;
    }

    public void Start(MessageBroker messageBroker)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = messageBroker.URL }.CreateConnection();

        foreach (Queue queue in messageBroker.Queues)
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(
                queue: queue.Name,
                durable: queue.Durable,
                exclusive: queue.Exclusive,
                autoDelete: queue.AutoDelete,
                arguments: null
            );

            EventingBasicConsumer consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                byte[] body = ea.Body;
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

                RouteMessage(queue, message);
            };

            channel.BasicConsume(
                    queue: queue.Name,
                    autoAck: queue.AutoAck,
                    consumer: consumer
                );
            hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", "It worked - from the subscriber");
        }
    }

    public void RouteMessage(Queue queue, string message) {
        if(queue.Name == "discovery") {
            nodeProcessor.Process(message);
        }
        if(queue.Name == "health") {
            healthCheckProcessor.Process(message);
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating connection to RabbitMQ instance.");
        channel.Close(200, "Goodbye");
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**From `HealthCheckProcessor.cs`**

```
public class HealthCheckProcessor : IHealthCheckProcessor {
    private IDataService dataService;
    private IHubContext<StatusHub> hubContext;

    public HealthCheckProcessor(IDataService _dataService, IHubContext<StatusHub> _hubContext)
    {
        dataService = _dataService;
        hubContext = _hubContext;
    }
    public void Process(string message) {
        HealthCheck health = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HealthCheck>(message);
        Node node = dataService.GetSingle(health.NodeId);
        node.Health = health;

        dataService.Update(node);
        Console.WriteLine("It's sending.");
        hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", "It worked - from the processor");
    }
}
```

**From the Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private IDataService _dataService;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private static IHubContext<StatusHub> hubContext;

    public NodesController(IConfiguration config, IDataService dataService, IHubContext<StatusHub> _hubContext)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        configuration = config;
        hubContext = _hubContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Send", "Blarg!");
        return "Well, I tried.";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean signalr-core, right? If so, it would be good if you change the tag.

Comment: What specifically is your problem? Since `IHubContext<MyHub>` is registered with the DI container, you can inject it into *anything*, controller or not, as long as that object is also being created by DI container, as a controller would be.

Comment: @ChisPratt the `IHubContext` may not be registered correctly. I only added `app.UseSignalR(); and `services.AddSignalR()` in `Startup.cs`. I'm not certain if/how to inject my `IHubContext<MyHub>` as a service. What do I use as the interface and the implementation?

Comment: I added my hub as services.AddSingleton<StatusHub>(); and it works fine for me. I never use the hub in my controller, I have an extra service for that.

Comment: @Nickdb93 is `ISubscriber` being injected properly into startup?

Comment: @Nkosi It appears to be, right? You'll notice my `Console.WriteLine()` in `HealthCheckProcessor` (which gets called by `Subscriber`, and when I had a `Console.WriteLine()` in `Subscriber`, it was able to see it fire. You'll also notice the `DataService` which saves the `HealthChecks` to persistence, which also gets fired becuase my DB data is what I expect it to be.

Comment: @Nickdb93 what about `IHubContext<StatusHub> _hubContext`? is it being injected into subscriber when resolved?

Comment: @Nickdb93 I ask because with all your edits to the original problem I and finding it difficulty seeing exactly what is your problem. You say some problems were solved. clarify.

Comment: @Dani I appreciate it, but I just tried that to no avail.

Comment: @Nkosi Originally, the program was unable to resolve my SignalR hub when i called `Subscriber`. Eventually, I decided to inject ISubscriber at the `Program.cs` level so that I could call it without instantiating it manually in `Startup.cs`. I thought that this way, my HubContext would properly be injected by the time I called `subscriber.Start()` on application startup in `Startup.cs`. It partially worked.... I didn't get any errors saying it was unable to resolve the service. However, now it silently fails to send SignalR messages.

Comment: @Nkosi does that make sense? I know the problems have jumbled around since I've been working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access services that are not available at the time you request them.

`Configure` is called after `ConfigureServices` specifically so that any services registered can be accessible.

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration _configuration) {
        configuration = _configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {        
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddTransient<ISubscriber, Subscriber>();
        services.AddTransient<IDataService, DataService>();
        services.AddTransient<IHealthCheckProcessor, HealthCheckProcessor>();
        services.AddTransient<INodeProcessor, NodeProcessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app, 
        IHostingEnvironment env, 
        IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, 
        IServiceProvider sp
    ) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            // CORS stuff);

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseSignalR(routes => {
            routes.MapHub<StatusHub>("Status");
        });

        //At this point all the necessary dependencies have been registered and configured
        var subscriber = sp.GetService<ISubscriber>();

        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => OnStartup(subscriber));
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => OnShutdown(subscriber));
    }

    private void OnStartup(ISubscriber subscriber) {
        // MessageBroker stuff
        subscriber.Start(messageBroker);
    }

    private void OnShutdown(ISubscriber subscriber) {
        subscriber.Stop();
    }
}
```

You should be able to now remove the convenience `ConfigureServices` when building the host.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

Comment: Working, nice job. Follow up, though. Why isn't the service available even though I injected it before anything in `Startup` was called? Why wasn't I able to use it in the constructor of `Startup`? (BTW I can't award bounty for 2 hours still)

Comment: At the time that subscriber was injected, signalR was not completely configured to be used. Which is why I requested it after. For example the controller would be requesting the context well after everything was completely configured.

Comment: Ah I see, I figured calling `services.AddSignalR()` in `Program.cs` was enough to do the trick for that. Bravo, thank you.